# Ansible - iterate over a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I built the following list but I don't succeed to iterate over it.
Should I use with_items? with_elements? or something else?

My goal is to iterate over all the hosts in the inventory, get their name and their IP, and finally print it.

```
- set_fact:
    list_of_hosts: |
      {% set myList = [] %}
      {% for host in groups['all'] %}
      {% set ignored = myList.extend([{'server_name': host, 'server_ip': hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }]) %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ myList }}


- debug: msg="{{ item.server_name }}"
  with_items: "{{ list_of_hosts }}"
```

Here is my list when I debug it:

```
TASK [common : debug] ************************************************************************************************

ok: [my1stServer] => {
    "msg": "            [{'server_ip': u'192.168.0.1', 'server_name': u'my1stServer'}, {'server_ip': u'192.168.0.2', 'server_name': u'my2ndServer'}]\n"
}
```

And here is the error but it is not really relevant :

```
fatal: [my1stServer]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'ansible.vars.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'server_name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'hosts.yml': line 19, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug: msg=\"{{ item.server_name }}\"\n  ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me for bluntness, but the proposed implementation makes it an effort to understand what the idea actually is. which is simple: to print some variables anyway present in `hostvars[host]` for a list of hosts picked by various criteria.
If we keep implementation close to that idea, implementation is simpler.

So what I'd do to create a list of hosts picked by group membership, or possibly 'hand picked' is to actually do what I just wrote :).
Consider this task list:

```
# this task creates an empty list
- name: create my_cool_list
  set_fact:
    my_cool_list: []
# this task adds to the list all hosts in groups we're iterating over
- name: update my cool list with whole groups
  set_fact: '{{my_cool_list + groups[curr_grp]}}'
  with_items:
  - grp1
  - grp2
  loop_control:
    loop_var: curr_grp
# this task adds to the list all hosts we're iterating over
- name: update my cool list with specific hosts
  set_fact: '{{my_cool_list + [curr_node]}}'
  with_items:
  - node001
  - node101
  loop_control:
    loop_var: curr_node

# now we can iterate over the list, accessing specific fields on each host
- name: go over my cool list and print ansible_init_mgr
  debug:
    msg: 'hostvars["{{curr_host}}"].ansible_init_mgr: {{hostvars[curr_host].ansible_init_mgr}}'
  with_items: '{{my_cool_list|default([], true)|list}}'
```

Furthermore, you can add safety `when:` by validating the key you're accessing is defined..

And, to print a selection of variables about each host, you should use jinja filter `map('extract',...)`:

```
- name: print some vars from each host
  debug:
    msg: {'server_name': '{{hostvars[curr_node]|selectattr("ansible_hostname")}}', 'ip_address': '{{hostvars[curr_node]|selectattr("ansible_eth0.ipv4.address")}}'}
  with_items: '{{my_cool_list|default([], true)|list}}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: curr_node
```

IF you want to increase readability though, you better write a filter plugin, which would do the above stuff, and hide iteration ugliness in readable way, so you can have:

Either (For generic approach, i.e. without renaming attributes)

```
- name: print some vars from each host
  debug:
    msg: '{{my_cool_list|multi_select_in_dict(["ansible_hostname", "ansible_eth0.ipv4.address")}}'
```

Or specific approach (so that you are using specific hard coded remapping of attributes...)

```
- name: print some vars from each host
  debug:
    msg: '{{my_cool_list|my_cool_filter}}'
```

Comment: Also, you better use `ansible_default_ipv4.address`.